# How set base package to scan subpackages for actions?

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

How can I tell to Struts 2 convention plugin to scan all subpackages of a package. I tried with this

```
<constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller" /> 
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators.basePackage" value="fi.fpf.mvc" />
```

and this

```
<constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller" /> 
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators.basePackage" value="fi.fpf.mvc.*" />
```

but they don't work. my actions end with `"Controller"` suffix. Someone knows how to do it?

**here's my `struts.xml`:**

```
<struts>

    <constant name="struts.convention.exclude.parentClassLoader" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.fileProtocols" value="jar,vfs,vfsfile,vfszip"/>
<constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller" /> 
    <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators.basePackage" value="fi.fpf.mvc" />


    <package name="fpf-default" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**and one action:**

```
@Action("indexController")
public class IndexController extends ActionSupport{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2613425890762568273L;


    @Action(value="loadIndex", results={
            @Result(name="indexView", location = "indexView", type="tiles")
    })
    public String loadIndex() {
        return "indexView";     
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<constant name="struts.convention.action.packages" value="fi.fpf.mvc.*"/>
```

if you are using convention plugin, then you should follow the class and package name conventions. Why not just name a base package to "struts" or "struts2" and with the default package locators it will be located. Also the classes should have names that matches `"Action"` suffix.

> You can tell the Convention plugin to ignore certain packages using
>   the property `struts.convention.exclude.packages`. You can also tell the
>   plugin to use different strings to locate root packages using the
>   property `struts.convention.package.locators`. Finally, you can tell the
>   plugin to search specific *root* packages using the property
>   `struts.convention.action.packages`.

See the [docs](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-Codebehindhelloworld).

Alternatively, you could set the base package and locator that match this package and any package under the base

```
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators.basePackage" value="fi.fpf.mvc"/>
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="fi,fpf,mvc"/>
```

Comment: before I had all action in one package named "controller" and I used this `<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="controller"/>` and it worked

Comment: No, it's impossible, I have myself tested it, everything works using locators with comma separated and without dots.

Comment: but the package of my action is fi.fpf.mvc.index and the other actions are located in other subpackages under fi.fpf.mvc!