# HTTP 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/modeldriven] and action name [datosUsuario] associated with context path [/FormularioMD]

Tags: java, struts2, model-driven, struts2-convention-plugin, action-mapping

I'm a beginner to struts2. I created a dynamic web project on eclipse so as to using struts 2. There are something wrong with it, and i just don not know why. the Console output is:

```
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/modeldriven] and action name [datosUsuario] associated with context path [/FormularioMD]. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:554)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:306)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:323)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1719)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have the following directory structure:

```
Resources
--src
  --action and model.
WebContent
--modeldriven
  --nuevo-usuario.jsp
  --datos-usuario.jsp
--WEB-INF
  --lib
  --web.xml
```

My JSP file to input data:

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="datosUsuario">
    <s:textfield name="nombre" label="Nombre" />
    <s:textfield name="username" label="Username" />
    <s:password name="password" label="Password" />
    <s:textfield name="edad" label="Edad" />
    <s:textfield name="fechaNacimiento" label="Fecha de Nacimiento" />
    <s:submit value="Enviar" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My action class, **NOTE:** I using annotations:

```
package com.java.rmo.controladores;

import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Namespace;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;

import com.java.rmo.modelos.Usuario;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

@Namespace(value = "/modeldriven")
@Action(value = "datosUsuario", results={
        @Result(name="success", location="/modeldriven/datos-usuario.jsp")
})
public class UsuarioAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Usuario> {

    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

     public Usuario getModel(){
            return usuario;
     }

     @Override
     public String execute() throws Exception {
         return SUCCESS;
     }
}
```

My JSP file to show result:

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Nombre: <strong><s:property value="nombre" /></strong> <br />
Username: <strong><s:property value="username" /></strong> <br />
Password: <strong><s:property value="password" /></strong> <br />
Edad: <strong><s:property value="edad" /></strong> <br />
Fecha de Nacimiento: <strong><s:property value="fechaNacimiento" /></strong>
</body>
</html>
```

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>struts2HelloWord</display-name>

<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

So, can anybody help me?, thank's.

Comment: What url are you hitting when you get that exception? It is better to put jsp-s under WEB-INF, in such way they won't be accessible directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Convention plugin, as the name suggests, works using naming conventions.

It searches for certain packages, and inside them, it looks for actions with certain names, or implementing a specific interface.

From [the documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-Codebehindhelloworld):

> By default, the Convention plugin will find all action classes that
>   implement `com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action` or whose name ends with the
>   word Action **in specific packages**.
>
> These packages are located by the Convention plugin using a search
>   methodology. **First the Convention plugin finds packages named `struts`,
>   `struts2`, `action` or `actions`. Any packages that match those names are
>   considered the root packages for the Convention plugin. Next, the
>   plugin looks at all of the classes in those packages** as well as
>   sub-packages and determines if the classes implement
>   `com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action` or if their name ends with `Action` (i.e.
>   `FooAction`)

Since your package is:

> `package com.java.rmo.controladores;`

the Convention plugin won't search for anything inside it.

**You have two options:**

- Refactor your package to include one of the names requested by the plugin, for example:

  > `package com.java.rmo.actions;`
- Add your package to the list of packages the plugin will scan for actions, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959696/1654265) .

I'd personally go with the first solution... stick to the default, and avoid yourself possible problems or unwanted side effects.

Comment: I think `controladores` = `actions`?! And the package name shorter name would be `com.java.rmo.actions`.

Comment: C'mon Roman, it's an example. Controladores means Controllers, and yes, he can choose to replace it instead of appending something to it... this is his choice, and a very unimportant one in this context. The point is that he must put at the end one of the four expected package names, what's before is not interesting. I've also linked a question of your in a question of mine... just bring it home! :)

Comment: I see the point is to use a package name, configured by default or change a configuration, but actions in S2 also known as controllers. Having two nested packages with similar names looks ugly.

Comment: Just helped you to removed a little noise, that's it, also FYI  I've upvoted this answer because it's correct and linked to the solution of mine. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Good luck to you too